# How to close a native web browser popup in Jasmine JS?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, selenium, jasmine, protractor

How to close a native web browser popup in Jasmine JS?

I can't succeed to close this dialog and it keep showing up in all the running.

Please your help!

The code:

```
describe('LiveSite Portal - Client perform a call', function() {

  it('LiveSite - Home Page', function() {
       liveSiteHome();
    });

  it('LiveSite Portal - Client perform a call', function() {

        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {      
        browser.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length - 1]);

            var alertDialog = browser.switchTo().alert().thenCatch(function (e) {
                if (e.code !== 27) { throw e; }
            })
            .then(function (alert) {
                if (alert) {
                    expect(alertDialog.getText()).toEqual("External Protocol Request");
                    return alert.dismiss()
                }

            element(by.css("span.hide-sm.ng-binding")).click();
            browser.sleep(3000); 
            });

            //close the native popup
            browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
            browser.sleep(5000); 
        });
    });
});
```

The actual result:

[image]

Comment: What is your end goal? Do you want to launch an application or do nothing? Also, are you tied to Google Chrome, or would be ok with a Firefox specific solution?

Comment: I want to "do nothing"  but I need to run it by chrome and firefox as well.. @alecxe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you cannot handle this kind of popup with `protractor`/`selenium` - it is not a javascript popup and you cannot switch to it or control. Your best bet is to avoid opening the popup in the first place by tweaking browser's desired capabilities, preferences.

I don't have a solution for google-chrome yet, but for Firefox you would need to set the following preferences by defining a custom Firefox Profile (see [How To](https://github.com/juliemr/protractor-demo/tree/master/howtos/setFirefoxProfile)):

- [network.protocol-handler.expose-all](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.protocol-handler.expose-all) -> false
- [network.protocol-handler.expose.callto](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.protocol-handler.expose.%28protocol%29) -> false

This way you are letting Firefox know not to handle the external protocol link and do nothing.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually, I just want to know that this popup is open in this test.

Comment: @IdanE then, you should not be testing a browser's ability to handle external protocols. Hope you get my point here. Thanks.